# Writing an algorithm to parse highly nested JSON

Tags: python, json, algorithm

I want to write an algorithm to parse JSON of a unknown length using python.  The highly nested JSON object contains comments to a post and some "comment threads" go longer than others so the resulting nested dictionaries should be of varying length.  I probably need some kind of recursive algorithm to walk down each "branch" of the JSON tree but don't know where to even start with this.  Can someone just point me in the right direction?

Comment: If this is an actual use case question, see the dupe, don't reinvent the wheel. If this is an assignment question, then this is not going to be reopened.

Comment: im asking how to parse JSON in python not javascript?

Comment: Sorry, should be right, now.